# SecurityContextHolder fails at casting the principal into user

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to get the current user using the getAuthentication, the problem is that it gives the error `java.lang.String cannot be cast to User`. I do not know why it gives me this error...

My domain User code:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String username;
...}
```

The UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Incorrect username");
        return user;
    }
}
```

And my Controller..:

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class IdentityController {

    @RequestMapping("/identity")
    public @ResponseBody
    PersistentEntityResource getAuthenticatedUserIdentity(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler){
        Object obj = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        User user = (User) obj;

        return resourceAssembler.toResource(user);
    }
}
```

The AuthenticationConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!Test")
public class AuthenticationConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(User.passwordEncoder);

        String rootUser = System.getenv("ROOT_USER");
        String rootPassword = System.getenv("ROOT_PASSWORD");
        if(rootUser == null || rootPassword == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Environment variable user or password not defined.");
        }else if(!userRepository.exists(rootUser)) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(rootUser);
            user.setPassword(rootPassword);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Some clues? I am using mongodb.

SOLVED: I didn't have the `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/identity").authenticated()` in the WebSecurityConfig, so obviously the user wasn't log in. Also, I didn't have the `.httpBasic()`

Comment: Can you post the Spring Security configuration you have? If the configuration is fine and user is authenticated, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() shoud return the UserDetails object

Comment: Do you mean the AuthenticationConfig file? Added.

Comment: Can you log SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() just before error?

Comment: Check this : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#obtaining-information-about-the-current-user

Comment: @EugenCovaci The object after getPrincipal() is a String, "anonymousUser". I am checking the documentation link now.

Comment: So actually the user is not logged in. You should check the login page. Are you sure you access /identity after the authentication?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Right now I am using Spring rest with angular, and I access with authentication headers... Maybe it is because of the WebSecurityConfig.

Comment: Can you put your project somewhere like Github?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164053/discussion-between-noki-and-eugen-covaci).